# How to add a border to a rectangle in Java using setBorder and JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, border, rectangles

I am trying to add a border to a `Rectangle` element and for some reason it will not work, is it not compatible with `JFrame`? I can set my entire `JFrame` to having a border, but it can't find `setBorder` with my rectangles. Here is my code:

```
package trivia;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Rectangle;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.border.Border;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Main extends JFrame{

boolean mainMenu = true;
static Color tan = Color.decode("#F4EBC3");
static Color darkGreen = Color.decode("#668284");
static Color buttonColor = Color.decode("#A2896B");
Rectangle header = new Rectangle(0, 0, 500, 100);
Rectangle body = new Rectangle(0, 100, 500, 400);
Rectangle start = new Rectangle(150, 150, 200, 40);

public Main() {
    setTitle("Trivia Game!");
    setSize(500, 500);
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
}
@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    Dimension d = this.getSize();
    Border blackline;

    blackline = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black);
    if(mainMenu = true){
        g.setColor(darkGreen);
        g.fillRect(header.x, header.y, header.width, header.height);
        g.setFont(new Font("Courier", Font.BOLD, 24));
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        drawCenteredString("Trivia Game!", d.width, 125, g);
        g.setColor(tan);
        g.fillRect(body.x, body.y, body.width, body.height);
        g.setColor(buttonColor);
        g.fillRect(start.x, start.y, start.width, start.height);


    }
}
public void drawCenteredString(String s, int w, int h, Graphics g) {
    FontMetrics fm = g.getFontMetrics();
    int x = (w - fm.stringWidth(s)) / 2;
    int y = (fm.getAscent() + (h- (fm.getAscent() + fm.getDescent())) / 2);
    g.drawString(s, x, y);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    Main m = new Main();
}

}
```

And when I add this in my `paint` function:

```
start.setBorder(blackline);
```

It gives me the error:

```
The method setBorder(Border) is undefined for the type Rectangle
```

I am not sure how I can make it recognize the `setBorder` function, can anyone help? All help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you're trying to draw the rectangle referenced by `start`. In that case, you want to be invoking a method on a Graphics, not on a Rectangle. So:

```
g.drawRect(start.x, start.y, start.width, start.height);
```

Comment: After creating the rectangle, how would I add a border? just using `g.setBorder();` or what?

Comment: Oh i see, the `drawRect` method actually creates a border around it, thank you!

Answer (score 4):

1. `Rectangle` does not have a `setBorder` method, instead, set the color of the `Graphics` context using `Graphics#setColor(Color)` and either use `Graphics#drawRect(int, int, int, int)` or `Graphics2D#draw(Shape)`
2. You're breaking the paint chain.  Painting is made up of a series of chained method calls, which when called correctly, paint the current component and its child components.  By not calling `super.paint` you're preventing from doing this and could cause any number of nasty side effects, none of which you really want...
3. You should avoid overriding `paint` of top level containers, like `JFrame`, for a number of reasons; they're not double buffered; there a bunch of other components sitting on top of the frame which may paint over it; etc.  Instead, create a custom component, extending from something like `JPanel` and override it's `paintComponent` method instead (ensuring that you call `super.paintComponent` first)...

See [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html), 
[Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) and [2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/) for more details